# android google sign in always error running in lollipop or above handleSignInResult:false

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Android Google sign in error when running in **lollipop** or above `handleSignInResult:false` but in `Kitkat` it's work normally.. I'm not sure maybe my SDK is error? or the code is error?

or maybe for **lollipop** to above have a different code for this login?

this my code

```
package com.emergency.e_place;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.emergency.e_place.Util.SessionManager;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    SignInButton signInButton;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private final int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;
    SessionManager session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        setSession();
        setGoogleSignInAccount();
        declareWidget();
        setClickWidget();
    }

    private void setSession() {
        session = new SessionManager(LoginActivity.this);
    }


    private void setButtonGooglesignIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d("Hasil", "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        Log.d("Hasil", "handleSignInResult:" + result.toString());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            String nama = acct.getDisplayName();
            String email = acct.getEmail();
            String id = acct.getId();
            String foto = String.valueOf(acct.getPhotoUrl());

            session.createLoginSession(id,nama,email,foto);


            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        } else {
            Snackbar.make(getCurrentFocus(),"Maaf Anda Gagal Login",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void setGoogleSignInAccount() {
        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
    }



    private void setClickWidget() {
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setButtonGooglesignIn();
            }
        });
    }

    private void declareWidget() {
        signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.signin_login_signin);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),connectionResult.getErrorMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

this is the logcat

```
07-16 15:23:32.959 26540-26540/com.emergency.e_place E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.emergency.e_place, PID: 26540
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=0, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.emergency.e_place/com.emergency.e_place.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.view.ViewGroup.getContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4756)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4799)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:211)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1754)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.view.ViewGroup.getContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.<init>(Snackbar.java:124)
                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:148)
                                                                           at com.emergency.e_place.LoginActivity.handleSignInResult(LoginActivity.java:76)
                                                                           at com.emergency.e_place.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(LoginActivity.java:54)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6833)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4752)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4799) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:211) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1754) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is while creating snakeBar you are providing invalid view to snake bar according to you lagcat.

`getCurrentFocus()` is not returning valid view.
Try another valid view for testing

```
Snackbar.make(getCurrentFocus(),"Maaf Anda Gagal Login",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

The log says the SnackBar is causing the problem. I would agree with Sohail to say that `getCurrentFocus()` is returning a `null`.

You could:

1. In your `onCreate`, instantiate a global variable to store the root view of the content and use that view to show the SnackBar
2. Replace SnackBar code with this:

   ```
   Snackbar.make(((ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0), yourString, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   ```

   This will return the parent of the current view and attach the SnackBar to it.

Comment: i try your code, and when sign in show the String.. so how fix that?

Comment: i sorry, i dont understand what you are trying to say

Comment: yes this solved so the app no force stop again, but it still failed to login. how to fix that?

Comment: im sorry bud, im not very experienced with Google Sign in. you'll have to start a new thread for that. Also, do accept this answer and upvote. Glad I could help! :)

Comment: Hey @E-Place if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @E-Place there cannot be an all in one solution to all the problems. The answer solves the problem you are referring to in the question.

Comment: and because it's not my main problem

Comment: Cool bro. No hard feelings. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about using methods that can return `null` such as `getCurrentFocus`. You can either remove it completely and use only the view that you `findById` like this:

```
View parentLayout = findViewById(R.id.root_view);
Snackbar.make(parentlayout, "This is main activity", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Or check whether `getCurrentFocus` is null and then use this, and otherwise the view returned by it.

Comment: what is root_view?

Comment: Whatever is the outermost view in your layout. Say LinearLayout that contains everything else (give it the `@+id/root_view` and reference it here).

Comment: it just modified the `snackbar` and my problem is not solved yet. still can't login

Comment: Well, login is something else entirely and has nothing to do with this. We're not here to write the whole app for you, this problem was fixed and accept the answer that helped fix it accordingly. If you cannot fix the new problem, ask a new question.